# Passing one class/struct vs passing several parameters

Tags: c#, performance, parameter-passing

Passing one class/struct vs passing several parameters

I am wondering about performance considerations.

Would it be better **performance-wise** to pass into a method call a class or a struct (which?) holding two int parameters and an object reference, or would it be better to pass these three as three parameters?

Note:
I am developing on the Unity3D platform, so it's possible some things work differently then the classical .NET

Comment: If it really matters, measure it. Otherwise don't bother.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you pass a `class`, then the first thing you need to do is create an object, which will later need to be garbage collected. Not a problem normally, but on some Unity target platforms that could be undesirable *if* you are doing this lots.

If you pass a `struct` *normally*, then it needs to copy the struct. If it was big enough for you to be asking questions about encapsulation (i.e. representing more than a few parameters), then it is probably non-trivially big, and could be a pain to copy all the time, especially if passing down a few layers.

Passing individual parameters is fairly well known, and shouldn't cause a huge problem. Optional parameters in 4.0 can make adding more parameters less painful, *but* they are still passed (just with their default values).

An interesting option **for unity** is passing a `struct` *by ref*, since this **doesn't** copy the contents (it just passes a reference to the value you created, typically on the stack), and **doesn't** require any garbage collection, i.e.

```
var args = new SomeArgs(123, "abc", 23.4F, false); // <=== a struct
SomeMethod(ref args);
```

However, in most useful cases, I can't see that this gains you much over just

```
SomeMethod(123, "abc", 23.4F, false);
```

unless of course you are passing the parameters down a few layers - in which case it has the advantage that it doesn't need any copying. But watch out: the values are no longer independent between layers in the call-stack (regular parameters, not passed `ref`, are isolated to the method).

I *think* that at least describes some of the things to *consider*, but I don't have a conclusive answer for you. If you want something more scientific, you probably need to measure.

Comment: The data is passed one level only.
So basically, I'd need to create a new struct, constructed with the parameters into the method call, then within the method, which is an event, I'll access the parameters.

Comment: @gStation I'd just pass them as parameters, then, assuming there aren't masses of them

Comment: It's just these 3 parameters (enum, int, object)

Comment: @gStation just pass them as regular discreet parameters

Comment: I've run some extensive tests where I passed references to structs and pointers to structs, as well as regular parameters and parameters by ref. The performance delta is astonishing. Processing 8 ints and running simple addition on them was over 15 times faster when using params vs. structs. Pointers to structs was the slowest.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on how much parameters are there.

If you have 10 parameters, it will be very difficult (readability and code management perspective) to manage it. It would be advisable to club all these parameters in a class and pass that class.

Performance point of view it will add a little overhead but its worth than passing all such parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using params if you're gonna pass only the object type data.

```
public static void myMethod(params object[] list)
    {
      // do something
    }
```

you can pass any number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your concern then you should go for structs.Structs are leight weight compared to class,which carry a lot of datastructure on the back of it.